# Numeric argument matching with match.arg()

Tags: r

In `match.arg()`, why can the `choices` argument be numeric but the `arg` argument value cannot? Is the function not supposed to be used to match numeric arguments?

The documentation file for `match.arg` shows the following, but makes no mention of numeric values

> **choices**   a character vector of candidate values

Ok, but it's not in the following example.

```
f <- function(year){
    match.arg(year, choices = 1995:2005)
}

f(2000)
# Error in match.arg(year, 1995:2005) : 
#  'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

g <- function(year){
   match.arg(as.character(year), choices = 1995:2005)
}

g(2000)
# [1] 2000
```

So a character string just matched an numeric value...interesting.

My purpose for using this function is to determine if the user-entered `year` is a member of a large vector of years, which is not necessarily a sequence (some are missing).

Also note that `year = NULL` won't work for me here, because that would mean the default year would be 1871 in my actual data, which I don't want.

Comment: The choices argument is to allow you to narrow down the argument list of a function that has multiple arguments.  You seem to miss the point of what it supposed to be doing. It's not supposed to be used as a switch-case sort of function on regular vectors.

Comment: I think the `choices` argument is to make sure `arg` is a member of the possible choices, and assign it as such...like to be used in `if` statements down the line, No?  I edited for clarity.

Comment: I'm still unclear why you would not be using `year %in% choices`

Comment: I could do that. I was also looking at `is.element(year, choices)`.  Is there a preferred way to match numeric args?  It's big data, so I'm trying to get to the result as fast as possible.

Comment: In the speed comparisons I have seen, `%in%` performs very well. It's really just a wrapper around `match` which is optimized in C. I wouldn't expect `match.args` to compete well in such a use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Snippet from `match.arg`

```
else if (!is.character(arg)) 
        stop("'arg' must be NULL or a character vector")
```

with no attempt at coercion to a character string.

From `?match.arg`

> Matching is done using `pmatch`, so arg may be abbreviated.

From the `?pmatch` Arguments section

> **x**
>   the values to be matched: converted to a character vector by as.character. Long vectors are supported.

Therefore, with `match.arg`, a user cannot use a numeric `arg` but can use a numeric `choices` vector. It has been my experience that `5` is not the same as `"5"`.